# Azure Portal Deployment Options inaccessible with custom roles

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, rbac

I have a few websites running in Azure and bitbucket repositories are connected to the test-slots. I'm trying to give the developer access to the Deployment Options (and Log) using the Azure portal without him being able to do anything destructive to the Web Application itself. 
I've found an article describing how to create [custom roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles), but whatever I try, I cannot give the developer readonly access to the Web App and still allow him to access the Deployment Options: both the Deployment Options and Continous Delivery (Preview) are greyed out.

What I've done is create a new role based on the existing "Website Contributor" role (because that one *does* show the Web App's Deplyment Options) and changed the microsoft.web/sites/* to read-permissions:

```
Microsoft.Authorization/*/read
Microsoft.Insights/alertRules/*
Microsoft.Insights/components/*
Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/read
Microsoft.Resources/deployments/*
Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/read
Microsoft.Support/*
Microsoft.Web/certificates/*
Microsoft.Web/listSitesAssignedToHostName/read
Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/read
Microsoft.Web/sites/read
Microsoft.Web/sites/*/read
Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/read
Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/*/read
```

However, it only works when I replace the last 4 lines with this

```
Microsoft.Web/sites/*
```

But here lies the problem: I do not want give the developer full access to the Web Apps. The thing that drives me crazy is that even if I query all actions for this resource provider using powershell

```
Get-AzureRMProviderOperation "Microsoft.Web/sites/*" | FT OperationName, Operation , Description -AutoSize
```

And if I add all these individually instead of Microsoft.Web/sites/*, then it still doesn't show the deployment options and continous delivery.

Does anyone know why I need to give full access to the sites or how I can add readonly access to the site and still get access to the deployment options?

Comment: Your title is a bit confusing as you refer to "readonly Website Contributor". Reader and Contributor are distinct role, so there is no such thing as "readonly Website Contributor". So is your goal to give Contributor access to the slots, and Reader access to the Production App? Please clarify question.

Comment: @David, I've created a custom role based on website contributor, because the role Website Contributor can see the Deployment Options and log. This role however has too much permissions, so I'm trying to narrow it down. Basically I would settle for the role Reader, IF that role would permit viewing of the deployment options and logs, but it doesn't. I'll adjust the title, but if you think of a more appropiate one: I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: There is no way today to give access to deployment logs to Readers. Note however that you can make someone contributor to a slot while being only reader on the Prod site. Yes, it's not exactly the same.